# Why would one Meteor client collection behave different from what is shown in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've been happily inserting collection docs via the client console and browsing those docs in my app and my command-line MongoDB client, with no problems... until today, when I modified one of my collections with some new fields via the MongoDB shell and now I get very strange behavior.

Here are some results in command-line MongoDB:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.pieceSizes.find()
{ "_id" : "LzZxiwj2i32E9EGnm", "name" : "3C", "length" : 39, "width" : 25.5, "countedSF" : 7 }
{ "_id" : "AePXzKFgB7M8Ewnf2", "name" : "4C", "length" : 51, "width" : 25.5, "countedSF" : 9 }
```

However, when I look on the client, I basically see blank docs; when I run this in the JavaScript console:

```
PieceSizes.find()
```

... and then I expand the LocalCollection, I only see the _id, eg:

```
Object {_id: "LzZxiwj2i32E9EGnm"}
```

I get the same results for findOne.  Why would the client not see all the data, starting after I modified things in the shell?

I'm looking in the right DB because I can edit other collections and see data changes correctly on both ends.

I'd love to have a full explanation, but I'll settle for simply getting my app with working data again.

**UPDATE**: I saw that there's a Meteor update so I ran it to update to 0.7.0.1, and now it gets even stranger.  If I do a findOne for that doc, I get the following object:

```
Object {0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: undefined, 3: undefined, 4: undefined, 5: undefined, 6: undefined, 7: undefined, 8: undefined, 9: undefined, 10: undefined, 11: undefined, 12: undefined, 13: undefined, 14: undefined, 15: undefined, 16: undefined, 17: undefined, 18: undefined, 19: undefined, 20: undefined, 21: undefined, 22: undefined, 23: undefined, 24: undefined, 25: undefined, 26: undefined, 27: undefined, 28: undefined, 29: undefined, 30: undefined, 31: undefined, 32: undefined, 33: undefined, 34: undefined, 35: undefined, 36: undefined, 37: undefined, 38: undefined, _id: "LzZxiwj2i32E9EGnm"}
```

That's right, it has key _id with the expected value like earlier but now also has keys 0-38 with undefined values.  But the MongoDB client still shows all the data I want (and no numbered keys).

So I figured I'd try to remove and insert my data again all on the client side, but when I perform an insert:

```
PieceSizes.insert({name:"1C", length:88, width:18, countedSF:10})
"YkgoAJehkyZmDbe7G"
```

... I end up with that output that looks like an ID ("YkgoAJehkyZmDbe7G") but no doc with that ID is defined (ie. findOne will not pull it up and a find will show a cursor with nothing like this ID in its results).  However, I can see a new doc on both browser console and command-line shell with nothing but an ID:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b7d0d81f4f910000000001") }
```

Note that it totally dropped all my other information.  Besides that, it has an ID that doesn't match the regular Meteor convention (ie. it created the typical Mongo ObjectId).  I suppose I can work with the ObjectId, but I cannot work if the client will not save any of my data nor read any of the extra data from what's already in the DB.

I guess the next step to try and export/import/reinstall data and tools.  Any workarounds welcome!

Comment: I didn't get it, is there a solution to solve this issue? I mean what should we do so browser mongo become sync with  server mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: using a 'length' property in your object will wreak havoc with the communication to/from the DB.

Looks like there are known issues with a 'length' field: 
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/594

Here are the symptoms.

**Inserts via client code, eg. the browser's JavaScript console**

Command: `PieceSizes.insert({name:"1C", length:88, width:18, countedSF:10})`

Return value (expected): a key (eg. `"YkgoAJehkyZmDbe7G"`), but one which isn't stored anywhere with the object and can't be used.

Stored info as seen in Mongo shell (unexpected): an object with a single field of _id, eg. `{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b7d0d81f4f910000000001") }`

Stored info as seen in browser client (unexpected): an object with a single field of _id, eg. `{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b7d0d81f4f910000000001") }`

**Inserts via a Mongo shell on the server**

Command: `db.pieceSizes.insert({name:"1C", length:88, width:18, countedSF:10})`

Return value (expected): none

Stored info as seen in Mongo shell (expected): an object with a generated _id, eg. `{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b85c2d42c8a8dc81bf0331"), "name" : "1C", "length" : 88, "width" : 18, "countedSF" : 10 }`

Stored info as seen in browser client (unexpected): an object with one _id key and 88 keys named "0" through "87"; all have an undefined value.  (Note that there is a case where the _id is an ObjectId, possibly caused by a meteor upgrade in my case.)

Comment: I didn't get it, is there a solution to solve this issue? I mean what should we do so browser mongo become sync with  server mongo?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things

When Meteor inserts a document it will use a string type `_id` such as `LzZxiwj2i32E9EGnm`. When its inserted from mongo its typically an `ObjectID` object such as `ObjectId("52b7d0d81f4f910000000001")`.

You can do this in meteor if you want by setting the `idGeneration` option of your collection to `MONGO` for example:

```
 PieceSize = new Meteor.Collection('pieceSizes', { idGeneration : 'MONGO' });
```

The reason this is done as a string in Meteor is so that you can easily use strings in URLs and map them to a specific ID. Its a little bit trickier using ObjectIDs since you would have to convert them back and forth to strings.

The reason of what looks like to be why you only get the `_id` field is you have a `fields` option set but to nothing during a publish. You can test this is the case by adding back auto publish

```
 `meteor add autopublish`
```

There are a couple of things that can cause the behavior you have:

#### Not publishing correctly

If it works after this it means that your publish rule doesn't set the fields correctly or you aren't returning documents correctly on a transform it could be either.

You need something like this

```
 Meteor.publish("pieces", function() {
     return PiecesSize.find({}, fields: { name: true, length: true, countedSF: true });
 });
```

So that those particular fields are published. After this you can disable auto publish.

If you don't set `fields` correctly you only get `_id` fields.

#### Not returning on a `transform`

If it is a transform such as this (or even using a Collection instead)

```
Docs.find({}. {transform: function(doc) {
    doc.value2
    return doc
});
```

don't forget to use `return` at the end of the transform if you don't you also get fields of just `_id` as results.

If you think its none of these it could be database corruption or something. You could use `meteor reset` and get a fresh start on your database.

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanations!  However, I found one part of my problem is the length property: using that in the client will jack up the the way inserts work.  I'll explain more in another answer.

Comment: I didn't get it, is there a solution to solve this issue? I mean what should we do so browser mongo become sync with  server mongo?